# Проблема с отображением адреса в адресной строке

Tags: веб-программирование, php, html, dreamweaver

Создал сайт со следующими настройками в dreamweaver:

[image]

[image]

Существует страница `C:\WebServers\home\yz4.ru\www\index.php`:

[image]

которая при попытке открытия в chrome (а в ie выдает тоже адрес `http://index.php` c сообщением, что невозможно отобразить страницу) выдает след.:

[image]

как видно из рисунка адрес в адресной строке не ожидаемый, а именно `index.php`,  а не `yz4.ru/index.php`. Наталкиваюсь не в первый раз - помогите устранить (может что в настройках не так задал).

Comment: localhost/index.php ... нет? у вас явно windows, используйте wamp http://www.wampserver.com/ru/

Да ещё на сколько я помню, дримвьювер не является сервером а просто средство разработки,чтобы открывать php на локальной машине нужен "сервер". ссылка выше.

Comment: @Олег Б я хочу пока weaver попользовальтся с ним осоиться пока что а что там оп поводу localhost/index.php вы написали - я не понял? у меня отображается адрес http://index.php.

Comment: 1) dreamweaver - пишите код
2) WAMP - смотрите результат работы

Comment: @ivan89, Используйте на здоровье Dreamweaver, но для работы нужен интерпретатор. Установите локальный сервер или же используйте только статические страницы (index.html).

Comment: @Deonis у меня Denwer стоит по поводу локального сервера.

Comment: @ivan89, перегружали Денвер после создания папки yz4.ru? И запускайте в браузере, как обычный сайт, прописав http://yz4.ru

Comment: @Deonis DEnwer перегружал а хотелсоь бы запускать из вивера.

Comment: Тогда пропишите в **URL-адрес** (2-ой скрин) - http://yz4.ru, и путь **Папка сервера** - до корня сайта